# How to Show value of hash map, if the value is in another class

Tags: java, hash

I'm stuck in something and I hope that somebody could help me. I'm new to java and try to use `Hashmap`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Map <Integer, Mahasiswa> daftarMahasiswa = new HashMap <Integer, Mahasiswa>();
Map <String, Buku> daftarBuku = new HashMap<String, Buku>();
Map <Integer, ArrayList<Buku>> katagori = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Buku>>();

Mahasiswa mahasiswa = new Mahasiswa("Bawal",150689999); 

daftarMahasiswa.put(1506899999, mahasiswa);
```

I've tried to use `Iterator` and `printallarray`. But, it always show the address of the class, not the value of the class.
Do you have any clue how to show the value of the class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: override the toString() method in your object class to print what you want.

Comment: show the code you are using for printing

Comment: create a toString() method in your class Mahasiswa. then you could just write objectName.toString(). This should help http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55

Comment: thanks friends. help me alot :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you the code to get the hashMap keys and its values, hope that helps.

For getting the keys.

```
SET<Integer> keys = daftarMahasiswa.keySet();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = keys.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
   Integer values = iterator.next();
   System.out.println(vaues);

}
```

if you want to get the values not the just keys add this line.

```
System.out.println(daftarMahasiswa.get(values);
```

There must be toString() method in your class to show its values currently its an object. check the example of toString() method in class and its return value
[link of example of toString() method](http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method)